# How to read custom .config file in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, configuration-files, config

I have a custom configuration file in my asp.net website, named `urls.config`, which contains simple key value, just for redirection purpose, now I want to read this file programmatically and also add values in this file, I am able to use XMLTextReader and XMLDocument to read value from this file, but i am unable to add values in this file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Here is my structure for the configuration file:

```
<rewriteMaps>  
  <rewriteMap name="StaticRewrites" />  
  <add key="/superstars4012" value="/article.aspx?articleid=4012" />  
  <add key="/superstars4013" value="/article.aspx?articleid=4013" />  
  <add key="/superstars4014" value="/article.aspx?articleid=4014" />  
  <add key="/superstar" value="/article.aspx?articleid=4012" />  
</rewriteMaps>
```

`XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("urls.config"));

        XmlElement element = doc.CreateElement("add");

        element.SetAttribute("key", txtAddVanity.Text);

        element.SetAttribute("value", "/article.aspx?articleid=4012");

        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(element);

        doc.Save(Server.MapPath("urls.config"));`


this works well if the file extension is .xml, but does not when i change it to .config, my requirement is .config, as redirects does not work in .xml

Comment: You want to add values? Do you realize that modifying web.config would unload the application domain hosting your application? web.config is for readonly configuration values of the application. If you want to dynamically update config values from within the application use a database or something.

Comment: actually i have rewrite defined in web.config, just to seperate redirects file, i have specified <rewriteMaps configSource="urls.config" /> and all the redirects are placed in this file....

Comment: @Abbas, this doesn't matter. Even external files referenced with `configSource` would be tracked by ASP.NET and modifying them would have the exact same effect as modifying the original web.config => unloading the application domain from memory. Is this what you want?

Comment: i dont want to update web.config file, just need to update the urls.config file which contains the above key values...

Comment: @Abbas, OK then, simply use a XmlReader and XmlWriter if there is no relation between web.config and this urls.config file. But as I said, if you use a `configSource` pointing to urls.config from within your web.config if you modify urls.config your application will restart.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: the redirects will be added at runtime by the client, and this has to be stored in this urls.config file so that those redirects take effect, so i need to update this file.

Comment: @Abbas, are you understanding my comments? How is this urls.config file related to web.config?

Comment: can you please have a look on my original post, i have updated it, the way i am currently saving it.

Comment: @Abbas, so if I understand you correctly you have a XML file that you want to read from and write to from within your ASP.NET application? Because ASP.NET is multithreaded environment you should ensure that while one thread is writing to the file other threads are not trying to read from it. You could use a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to properly synchronize the access to such shared resource while manipulating it with XmlReader and XmlWriter. As far as the extension of your file is concerned, XmlDocument shouldn't really care whether it's .xml or .config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As eloquently stated in this [msdn](http://forums.asp.net/t/893902.aspx/1?Edit%20web%20config%20file%20during%20runtime%20) post, modifying the web.config file while the application is running is certainly possible (as it is just text, after all) but would be a very bad idea, in that modifying the config file will result in the application being restarted on the server -- ending any sessions with current users, and all new visitors seeing an error page until the application is restarted. Certainly not ideal.

From the look of your code,

```
<add key="/superstar" value="/article.aspx?articleid=4012" />
```

**It appears you are doing url rewriting from a static url to a dynamic query string. There are much better ways of accomplishing this.** One is the IIS module "user-friendly urls." I have very few problems that I couldnt solve using this module.

Its logic is as follows:

1. user enters "http://www.domain.com/page-this-or-that
2. IIS has a regex rule that matches that url pattern and catches the url
3. the user is directed to http://www.domain.com/page?id=page-this-or-that
4. You recieve the querystring and store it in a string
5. You then execute a database call that retrieves and displays the database row with the title "page-this-or-that"

This would be much easier to maintain, as well as safer for your application and your users.

-Cheers!